# My former prof switched university and now I can't ask him in person for a LOR - should I try to see him?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter, professorship

My former prof switched university and now I can't ask him in person for a letter of recommendation - should I try to see him in person? I've read [on here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16610/how-to-obtain-a-fair-recommendation-letter-from-a-professor-who-knows-me-via-cou?rq=1) that asking him via email might not be the best approach.

I could travel to that city - I have a friend living there - but it's not close and I am not sure how important it is I see him in person. I also don't want to annoy my professor with this, so I'm not sure.

The problem is only that it's been 2 years since I studied with him, and I did not do research with him, just submitted an excellent essay. So I think it would probably be good to remind him a bit of who I am. What would you advise me to do?

While "Should I ask my professor by email or in person", is related, it doesn't answer my question. I'm asking whether travelling to that professor in order to see him in person is overkill.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of this question - I thought I had read the bit about "submitted an excellent essay" ... : https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102562/can-i-remind-a-professor-that-i-submitted-a-good-essay-in-her-class-lor-requ

Comment: @SolarMike I think the other question is about phrasing the request, this is about visiting the prof.

Comment: @henning I did put "basically" - would have thought the OP would have sent the email by now and probably received the reference... Does this sound like an exercise in procrastination...

Comment: @SolarMike These are still separate questions though. You also don't know whether I am referring to the same professor in both questions.

Comment: So, TWO professors who won't remember you - we do... And both answers suggest sending an email...

Comment: First, it does not matter what the personal background of my questions is and there is no problem with me asking two questions about a *single* professor, as long as the questions are conceptually different - and they are. Second, I didn't say none of the professors will remember me, - I only said that it's been a few years since I studied, so I am naturally worried that my professors might need a little reminder. Nothing weird about that.

Comment: 'And both answers suggest sending an email...' - just because the answers to the questions are pointing in the same direction, this does not make the questions identical or duplicates. This is a ridiculous argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better to request a recommendation letter in person after class or by email?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34211/is-it-better-to-request-a-recommendation-letter-in-person-after-class-or-by-emai)

Comment: @MadJack This is closer, but there is no "after class" in the present scenario. Meeting the prof would involve travel.

Comment: @henning Then the question should be closed as "The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a certain person’s preferences ..."

Comment: @henning it is "after class" just not in the 5 minutes after class - 2 years after...

Comment: @MadJack I think it's pretty clear that there's no need to travel, so there's an objective answer. It's not a terribly relevant question overall, but I can't see a reason to close.

Comment: @SolarMike I've read it the other way, but your interpretation makes sense as well.

Comment: @henning all this really boils down to : “send email : get reference : send application : move on “...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't think a visit is necessary (and I don't see where in the linked thread it says otherwise). Even if you were to visit him, you would contact him first to make an appointment, presumably by email.

Why not send a mail in which you both [ask for a letter of recommendation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24592/email-to-a-professor-after-long-time-for-recommendation) and whether the prof would like to talk to you to refresh his memory (be it in person or on the phone)?

Comment: "be it in person or on the phone" or via Skype!

Answer (score 16):

The question you link is about getting a letter of recommendation from a professor in your own university. In that situation, it makes sense to talk face-to-face. However, when the professor is in a different city, this is no longer necessary or even reasonable.

Honestly, I'd find it kinda creepy if you arranged a meeting with me and the smalltalk went

**Me:** So, how come you're in town? [Thinks: *probably visiting friends or something and just dropped by because they were here*.]
**You:** I spent two hours travelling here just to talk to you for fifteen minutes and, when we're done, I'm going to spend two hours travelling back.
**Me:** [Thinks, *er, how do I say "You know about telephones, right?" without sounding like a jerk?*]  Um. ... ... Ookay.

Comment: haha, i love that! yeah, true! I do have friends in that town and will be visiting this year anyways, so I would have somehow arranged it that way, but you're so right.

Answer (score 9):

If he is someone who is likely to write you a good LOR then he is unlikely to be annoyed by an email asking for that. Traveling there seems like overkill to me. On the other hand, if it is really, really important to you then it is unlikely to hurt to ask him in person.